# Tkinter problem: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, tkinter

wish to get some guidance here. Initially when there is only 2 frame, StartPage and SplitTraining, the GUI works well. However, when I added the deepLearning class, it started to have t he problem of TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args,**kwargs)
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack()
        self.frames={}
        for F in (StartPage, dataSplit, deepLearning):
            frame = F(self.container, self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.configure(width=600, height=900)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
            self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, controller):
        frame=self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise()
```

This is the class of deepLearning

```
class deepLearning(tk.Frame):
            
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        pb1 = Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=600)
        pb1.pack(expand=True)
        b1 = Button(self, text="Choose Folder",font=('Times_New_Roman',16), command=lambda:[inputFilesDir(),step()], fg="white", bg="black")
        b1.pack()
```

Comment: Did you mean: `frame = F(self.container)`?

Comment: I don't think so, when I remove self, there are 1 new error, which is TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'controller'

Comment: This code has no problem initially when the code is written as
for F in (StartPage, dataSplit):, 
However, there is problem when the code is written as
for F in (StartPage, dataSplit, deepLearning):

Comment: If all your other two classes take two parameters, you could make `deepLearning` take two as well: `def __init__(self, parent, _):`

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your code requires that each page accepts the same two parameters: `parent` and `controller`. Since you're using this class like the other pages then it needs to accept the same parameters even if you don't use them.

```
class deepLearning(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
#                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```